# How to find references/usages of indexer (that is implemented in external class)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use an external library where a class implements an indexer. I want to find all the usages of this in my solution. Other solutions suggest right clicking on the this[] expression in the class that implements it, but I can't do that because it's an external library.

```
var result = libraryClassInstance[index]
```

Note that there are several instances of this class throughout my solution, so I can't simply go through the usages of `libraryClassInstance`.

I know ReSharper can do this, but is it possible without?

Comment: may be shift+F12 ?

Comment: Not sure if this is because of resharper or not, but I can search for indexer usages by right-click - find usages without a problem.